# Passing int[] to function with argument int *

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

I've a function which takes an `int *` as argument but I've an `int[]` , how can I pass the argument to it?

I used this method but i think it's not efficient:

```
void myFunc(int * ar);
...
int main(){
  int ar[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int *ar2=new int [5];
  memcpy(ar2,ar,5*sizeof(int));
  myFunc(ar2);
}
```

passing array itself causes compilation error.

Comment: it should compile, it would help when we know what the error is exactly

Comment: Arrays decays naturally to pointers, for example when passing them as arguments to functions. Therefore you can pass an array of `int` to a function expecting a pointer to `int`. You need to elaborate on what problems you have, like giving us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem you have, and including the actual errors you have. See e.g. [here for a working example](http://ideone.com/YuJbHq) of a function taking a pointer, and is passed an array.

Comment: Both `myFunc(ar)` and `myFunc(&ar[0])` should work fine. Can you post the exact error message.

Comment: [Can't produce any error](http://ideone.com/A5HYfe)

Comment: it should compile to pass just array name.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly pass an int[] as an int* parameter. An array can be decayed into a pointer.

This code will compile:

```
void myFunc(int * ar);
...
int main(){
  int ar[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  myFunc(ar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Pass `int[]` to function with argument `int *`,but the function can not know the length of the array.so you should add one more argument to the function,like: `myFunc(int *arr,int length)`

Comment: Well actually you probably shouldn't use C arrays in C++ code at all. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

an array can be converted into a pointer so you can pass the argument like this:

> myFunc(ar2);

since ar2 is an array we can pass the array because the parameters in myFunc
is pointer to an int which is ar2

heres how it works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void myFunc(int *ar)
{
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    std::cout << *(ar + i ) << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
int ar[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int *ar2=new int [5];

memcpy(ar2,ar,5*sizeof(int));
myFunc(ar2);

delete ar2; /// dont forget to de allocate :)
return 0;
}
```

output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: @DevSolar My comment referred to the original leading sentence, "arrays are pointers".

Comment: Your example code somewhat obfuscates the fact that arrays can be *decayed* into pointers (i.e., you could pass `ar` to `myFunc()` as well). The whole `memcpy()` thing is just muddying the waters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just passing the name of the array i.e. ar.

> The name of the array is actually the address of the first element of the array,  hence passing it in a function that takes an argument of type `int *ar` is the way to do it!

`myFun(ar)` will do the job just fine;

Comment: Nitpick: While the name of an array *happens* to be the address of its first element, and can *decay* into a pointer to its element type, it **is not** a pointer to the first element. The difference will matter e.g. for `sizeof()`, templates and the like. (I.e., the `typeid()` of `int[5]` is `int[5]`, not `int*`.)